# what is the default max Codecache size in Java 8

Tags: java, linux

What is the default maximum Codecache size for an Oracle Java 8 64-bit server VM?

I believe the relevant setting is ReservedCodeCacheSize.  I have seen two different values for the default ReservedCodeCacheSize:

- [This Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/codecache.htm) says it is 48M.
- The following command says it is ~250M:

> ```
> $ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version -server | grep ReservedCodeCacheSize
> uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                     = 251658240        {pd product}
> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
> $ uname -va
> Linux tst-job3 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 17:27:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) it is 240MB.

Personally I tested it on Windows 10.
On a version of the jre 7 x86 it gave me a limit of 50331648 bytes (48MB).
On a version of the jre 8 x64 it gave me a limit of 251658240 bytes (240MB).
On a version of the jre 8 x86 it gave me a limit of 251658240 bytes (240MB).

It would seem the values on the page [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/codecache.htm) you linked are for a different version, note the 'embedded' in the url.

The [Java embedded](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html) is for smaller/less powerful machines then the standard computer.